# How do I pick an specific version from previous commits in git?

Tags: git

I need to revert files from various commits to their previous state.

The reason is we won't deliver a particular functionality in this release.

I have spotted the commits already.

I think cherry-pick and/or rebase is in order but the search results I have confuse me a bit more.

How do I pick an specific version from previous commits in git?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to revert only a single file to its state in a previous commit, use `checkout`:

```
git checkout <previous commit SHA> -- /path/to/file
```

If you want to reverse an entire commit, use `revert`:

```
git revert <SHA of commit to undo the effects of>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one file you are trying to return to an earlier state then checkout is the right solution

```
git checkout <sha-1 hash in hex> filename.ext
```

if you wish to return your entire folder/commit to an earlier state

```
git revert <sha-1 of commit to reverse>
```

please note that with `revert` the sha-1 hash is of the ***commit you are trying to reverse*** rather than the one you are trying to revert to, this was not what I initially expected and I kept doing it wrong, and getting very frustrated when it gave me indecipherable error messages when I tried.